# Why is my test accuracy different then in keras documentation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I've trained a mnist convnet using exactly the same code as on that page of keras documentation:
https://keras.io/examples/mnist_cnn/

It achieved accuracy of 84.12% after 12 epochs when trained on my RTX 2060.

```
Epoch 12/12
60000/60000 [==============================] - 4s 64us/sample - loss: 0.9022 - accuracy: 0.7269 - val_loss: 0.6563 - val_accuracy: 0.8412
Test loss: 0.6562569307327271
Test accuracy: 0.8412
```

However, documentation claims it gets to 99.25% accuracy after 12 epochs when trained on GRID K520 GPU.

The question is: why is there such a huge difference between their results and mine if the parameters where the same?
Is this because GPUs are very different? Or maybe there's something wrong with my hardware, cuda setup etc. (I'm using tensorflow as keras backend btw)

I've also heard RTX GPUs use so called "tensor cores". Can this be the reason for difference in results?

Comment: There's no reason to accuracy change this much for a change in GPUs. It's obviously something in your code.

Comment: Hardware differences should affect the training speed, but not the accuracy.  Yes, ConvNet should achieve near-perfect accuracy on MNIST.  Is there somewhere to compare your setup with one known to work under comparable configurations?

Comment: Probably a difference in code, how you process the data, which optimizer you chose, etc....

Comment: The code is exaclty the same as in documentation except i import keras from tensorflow instead of doing it directly. The only software setup i did was installing anaconda and then tensorflow-gpu which takes care of all the cuda dependencies. I tested it on both ubuntu 18 and win10 and the result is exactly the same after 12 epochs although accuracy still rises if I run it for more epochs. I still have no idea what might be wrong if not the hardware